# Modifications on css file are not visible

Tags: css

I have this css file included as https://****.com/wp-content/themes/my-listing/assets/dist/editor-styles.css?ver=2.4.3&wp-mce-4960-20190918 in the admin page.

I have made some manual modifications on  https://****.com/wp-content/themes/my-listing/assets/dist/editor-styles.css (I have added some css code in this file)

However, these modifications are not visible on  https://****.com/wp-content/themes/my-listing/assets/dist/editor-styles.css?ver=2.4.3&wp-mce-4960-20190918

How can I make these modifications that I made in the **editor-styles.css** file, also be visible in my admin page , that has included **https://****.com/wp-content/themes/my-listing/assets/dist/editor-styles.css?ver=2.4.3&wp-mce-4960-20190918?**

Comment: Have you cleared your caches?

Comment: you have provided too little information to determine problem , what are you doing and what are you trying to get done , but if it is plugin or theme generated file i could just asume that is has minified version which is the version finally deployed by your plugin/theme , to test does your custom css work would just recomend adding same lines to your theme's style.css and to add '!important' to the rules values. example : ```.header-top {
background-color: red !important;
}
``` if you would provide more information what generates css and what you trying to achive would help futher determinati

Comment: Yes, I can change color, it seems to only be a problem with the tinymce editor